# JavaScript DOM-manipulations: createTextNode() versus element.textContent

Tags: javascript, dom

For creating a new HTML-element in JavaScript I can use:

```
let li = document.createElement('li');

li.textContent = val;

list.appendChild(li);
```

Or:

```
let li = document.createElement('li');
let text = document.createTextNode(val);

li.appendChild(text);
list.appendChild(li);
```

I have seen both variations and both seem to work equally well. The only difference seem to be that the first variation has a line code less.

**But what's the preferable way to append elements to a parent node? And for what reason?**

Or is it just a matter of personal preference and doesn't really matter?

Comment: you mean `li.appendChild(text);` ...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Sorry. Have corrected it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `createTextNode()` is safe and precise. `textContent` is more versatile: its text can be appended as you have described or with the `+=` operator as RCB mentioned. If the `=` is used, then it will overwrite existing text. It can also read  all the text within an element, but keep in mind that it returns **all** the text including the text of the target's descendant elements as well. BTW,  if you ask what is *"preferable"*, may be interpreted as asking one's opinion which may get your question closed. Having said that, I prefer `textContent` because of it's versatility.